# passing uitextfield and datepicker value to UItable View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am trying to do reminder app for iOS7 but my data from `UITextField` and `UIDatePicker` wont display on my `UITableViewCell`.
The table cell is blank (*sorry for my bad english*)

This is my **AddToDoViewController.m** which has the `UITextField` and `UIDatePicker`

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self.itemText resignFirstResponder];

    //Get the Current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    //Scheule the notification
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show the To Do List";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
     //Requested to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    //Dismiss the view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

This is my **ToDoViewController.m** which is the tableView that gets data from the AddToDoViewController and displays it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                                 name:@"reloadData"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Get list of local notification
    NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Display notification info
    [cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[localNotification.fireDate description]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)reloadTable {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints to see whats going on and if the notifications are being scheduled? Are you reloading the table view after you create a new notification?

Comment: where are you allocating cell?

Comment: Did you register the  class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method for the cell to be returned in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:  call.

Comment: @nkongara do u mean the identify in the mainstoryboard? i am new on xcode so i dun quite understand what are u saying

Comment: yes.. the notifications did pop out.. but the table cell did not have any data in it.. i did reloadData @PeterFoti

   ' - (void)reloadTable
    {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }'

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov i edited the code.. i posted my whole code on it..

Comment: does `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];` in `-numberOfRowsInSection` return any value (_basically, how many rows does your table have after `reloadData` is called_)?